# Jackson: simple mapping

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have pojo:

```
public class Address {
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String building;
    private String room;
```

And controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test_get_corporate_footprint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getCorporateFootprint(@RequestParam("officeLocation") String officeLocation) {
    System.out.println(officeLocation); //{"country":"Belarus","city":"Minsk","street":"Bahdanovicha","building":"1/3v","room":"3"}
}
```

But when I change controller method to accept Address as argument it returns null:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test_get_corporate_footprint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getCorporateFootprint(@RequestParam("officeLocation") Address officeLocation) {
    System.out.println(officeLocation);//null
}
```

What is wrong?

```
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.model.Address'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.model.Address': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map complex types (as your Address Object)  to requestParameters(i.e http:/localhost?param1=1&param2=2) without adding custom logic for handling them.

Spring does that by using custom argument resolvers to pre-populate a certain object type from request parameters( for example [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html)).

Also when issuing a HTTP GET request on an server you cannot pass a body/content, so a more flexible solution would be using the HTTP POST method with your object represented as a JSON in the request body.

For taking advandage of thie feature you can use the `@RequestBody` annotation on your method parameter.

So for your controller method to be able to receive the Address Object your should add the following changes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test_get_corporate_footprint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getCorporateFootprint(@RequestBody Address officeLocation) {
    System.out.println(officeLocation);
}
```

Also be sure to  have the Jackson libraries on your classpath.

You can then issue a post request using

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"country":"someCountry","city":"city"}' http://server/test_get_corporate_footprint
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the method to RequestMethod.POST, and issue a POST instead of a GET with expected json as payload.

You may also need to configure spring to use json serializer.